# Bootstrap - Sidebar collapsable and fixed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sidebar

I just followed this:

http://bootply.com/109746#

But I want to add affix to the sidebar for staying on place while scrolling on smartphone. I don't want the affix on big devices.

Comment: you will need to disable it by removing class by `jQuery`

Comment: may be help to you this question  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738541/bootstrap-3-offcanvas-menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738541/bootstrap-3-offcanvas-menu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in `position: fixed;top: 48px;` in .nav ul tag but it must be add where mobile detect.

[**DEMO bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/render/114728) re-size window and check.